# C header files #include statements and dependencies

Tags: c, opengl, struct, include

This is a question that I have been reading a lot about but I am still unclear how things work as I am getting building errors or incomplete type lint errors.

I have a project requiring opengl that I am writing low level opengl function, then I want to build on top of those translation [here after referred to as TU] units to build more higher level TU.

for example.

I have a common_structs.h that defines a few things like this:

```
common_structs.h
#ifndef COMMON_STRUCTS_H
#define COMMON_STRUCTS_H

#include <OpenGL.h>

struct renderable_2D {
    ...
    float angle;
    GLshort vertex_count;
    GLfloat vertices[12];
    GLfloat colors[16];
    GLshort indices[6];
    GLfloat tex_coords[8];
    ...
};

struct texture_2D {
    ...
    GLuint texture_id;
    ...
};

struct default_shader {
    const char* vertex_shader_srouce;
    const char* fragment_shader_source;
    GLuint shader_program;
};

struct camera_2D {....};

#endif /* COMMON_STRUCTS_H */
```

I declared these structs in their own header file to avoid circular dependencies.
This file isn't compiled but I need to `#include opengl` to clear the lint warnings for the GLtypes.
Next up there are header and source TU that implement the functionality for these types. Typically

Let's look at renderable_2D for example:

```
#ifndef RENDERABLE_2D_H
#define RENDERABLE_2D_H

#include "../../common/common_structs.h" //include the definition of renderable_2d

struct renderable_2D* ren2d_new(void);
struct renderable_2D* ren2d_set_uv(struct renderable_2D* out, const float uv[]);
struct renderable_2D* ren2d_set_tint(struct renderable_2D* out, const float r,
                                     const float g, const float b,
                                     const float a);
struct renderable_2D* ren2d_set_alpha(struct renderable_2D* out, const float a);
struct renderable_2D* rend2d_set_z_index(struct renderable_2D* out,
                                         const int index);
struct renderable_2D* rend2d_set_angle(struct renderable_2D* out,
                                          const float angle);

#endif /* RENDERABLE_2D_H */
```

and the some of the source file for this:

```
#include "../headers/renderable_2D.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
```

this file includes the header and implement the functions. Next there's one more header only file.

core_graphics.h

```
#ifndef CORE_GRAPHICS_H
#define CORE_GRAPHICS_H


#include "renderable_2D/headers/renderable_2D.h"
#include "default_shader/headers/default_shader_2D.h"
#include "default_camera_2D/headers/default_camera_2D.h"

#endif /* CORE_GRAPHICS_H */
```

this is a header only TU again and will include all the sub TU that make up this part of the library. It's supposed to be built as a shared library so next up the ladder is another shared library that will 
`#include core_graphics/core_graphics.h`

this is where the problem comes in. Say I have another TU main.c, main looks like this.

main.c

```
#include "core_graphics/core_graphics.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   struct renderable_2D* rend = (struct renderable_2D*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct renderable_2D));
   return 0;
}
```

the line where I try to calloc the struct I get lint errors saying

```
invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'struct renderable_2d'
```

now incomplete types says it cant find the definition of the struct renderable_2D but, from the source listed above, should it get included?

core_graphics.h has the definition of common_structs.h which holds the definition of the struct?

struct renderable_2D --> common_structs.h --> core_graphics.h --> main.c

Comment: your error message doesn't match your code -- notice how `2D` is differently capitalized! You will need to make double sure you don't have typos. Try to make a minimal example. Try to omit `struct` inside of `sizeof()`

Comment: @MarcusMüller Removing `struct` from `sizeof` probably won't work, because OP hasn't `typedef`'d any of his structs.

Comment: What compiler do you use? What include paths and flags? Does it omit some warnings about invalid paths for example? Can you enable more warnings? I think relative include paths may be a problem.

Comment: i didn't typedefs yet since it's very low level stuff at this moment. There are no file path errors. I am using vim & youcompleteme.

Comment: The error message complains that at the point where the error occurs, the full declaration of type `struct renderable_2d` is not visible.  Of course, as  Marcus Müller observed, that doesn't match up with your code (identifiers are case-sensitive).  There's not much more we can say, as we can hardly divine what is the actual source code.